# Cast from '[[AnyHashable : Any]]' to unrelated type '[AnyHashable : Any]' always fails

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

### Update

How can I fix this?

```
guard let imgUrl = url?.absoluteString else { return }
let imageURL = [AnyHashable("imageUrl"): imgUrl]  as [AnyHashable : Any]
let postTimeValue = [AnyHashable("postTimeStamp"): currentPostTimeStamp] as [AnyHashable: Any]
let timeValue = [AnyHashable("timeStamp"): media.timeStamp!] as [AnyHashable: Any]
let mediaRef = postRef.child("\(mediaNum)")
let caption = [AnyHashable("Caption") : caption] as [AnyHashable: Any]

let dataToUpdate = [imageURL, caption, timeValue, postTimeValue] as? [AnyHashable: Any]
mediaRef.updateChildValues(dataToUpdate!)
```

I get the bellow error on the last line

> Cast from '[[AnyHashable : Any]]' to unrelated type '[AnyHashable : Any]' always fails

I would think it would work given this example by firebase:

```
let updatedUser = ["name": "Shannon", "username": "shannonrules"]
let ref = Firebase(url: "https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com")

let fanoutObject = ["/users/1": updatedUser, "/usersWhoAreCool/1": updatedUser, "/usersToGiveFreeStuffTo/1", updatedUser]

ref.updateChildValues(updatedUser) // atomic updating goodness
```

---

[I have read this article from firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html?m=1), and would like to implement it into my project. The problem however is that I do not understand well what it is saying.

**Can someone explain in simple terms how the fan out feature works?**

For example:

What is happening here?

```
let updatedUser = ["name": "Shannon", "username": "shannonrules"]
let ref = Firebase(url: "https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com")

let fanoutObject = ["/users/1": updatedUser, "/usersWhoAreCool/1": updatedUser, "/usersToGiveFreeStuffTo/1", updatedUser]

ref.updateChildValues(updatedUser) // atomic updating goodness
```

It seems like fanoutObject was never used.

Comment: It indeed looks like the last line should be using `fanoutObject` instead of `updatedUser`. Did you give it a try?

Comment: Tried it and it looks like it is a mistake. There are many mistakes in swift syntax throughout the article as well @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: I you give me a link to the article, I'll see if it's something we can update.

Comment: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html?m=1 Also updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created four `[AnyHashable : Any]` dictionaries. To join these dictionaries as another `[AnyHashable : Any]` dictionary, you shouldn't wrap the dictionaries in an array and type case as `[AnyHashable : Any]`. Use reduce and merging methods to join all the dictionaries

```
let dataToUpdate = [imageURL,postTimeValue,timeValue,caption].reduce([AnyHashable: Any]()) { (result, dict) in
    result.merging(dict, uniquingKeysWith: { (_, new) in new })
}
ref.updateChildValues(dataToUpdate)
```

Or

```
var dataToUpdate = [AnyHashable: Any]()
guard let imgUrl = url?.absoluteString else { return }
dataToUpdate[AnyHashable("imageUrl") = imgUrl as Any
dataToUpdate[AnyHashable("postTimeStamp") = currentPostTimeStamp as Any
dataToUpdate[AnyHashable("timeStamp") = media.timeStamp! as Any
let mediaRef = postRef.child("\(mediaNum)")
dataToUpdate[AnyHashable("Caption") = caption as Any
ref.updateChildValues(dataToUpdate)
```

Or

```
var dataToUPdate = [AnyHashable: Any]()
dataToUPdate.merge(imageURL) { (_, new) in new }
dataToUPdate.merge(postTimeValue) { (_, new) in new }
dataToUPdate.merge(timeValue) { (_, new) in new }
dataToUPdate.merge(caption) { (_, new) in new }
```

Comment: For the first line of the top bloack of code I get : Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Comment: @NCT127 Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: on this line: let dataToUpdate = [imageURL,postTimeValue,timeValue,caption].reduce([AnyHashable: Any]()) { (result, dict) in

Comment: @NCT127 Try last block